# Which Search Criteria are available in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

While compiling a filter-set for a repository search criteria, I was wondering if I can make use of all known Magento **1** methods or if there are any differences.

Where are theses defined in the code (if), is there some kind of list maybe?

Answer (score 5):

In Magento 2.1.0 I was able to spot a list of filter criteria within the API inside a comment (file: vendor/magento/framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php:39)

```
 * - ["from" => $fromValue, "to" => $toValue]
 * - ["eq" => $equalValue]
 * - ["neq" => $notEqualValue]
 * - ["like" => $likeValue]
 * - ["in" => [$inValues]]
 * - ["nin" => [$notInValues]]
 * - ["notnull" => $valueIsNotNull]
 * - ["null" => $valueIsNull]
 * - ["moreq" => $moreOrEqualValue]
 * - ["gt" => $greaterValue]
 * - ["lt" => $lessValue]
 * - ["gteq" => $greaterOrEqualValue]
 * - ["lteq" => $lessOrEqualValue]
 * - ["finset" => $valueInSet]
```

The file comment has more information. Link to the public repository on Github:

- [`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php` (2d368d0)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2d368d0134597257ef5697a4bcbb7f69f2aebed8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php#L39)

Alan Storm has a higher-level introduction into the topic as well:

- [Magento 2: Understanding Object Repositories](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories)